# Cordova synchronous permanent local storage

Tags: cordova, local-storage

Based on my research, `localStorage` is unreliable for Cordova/Phonegap apps on iOS since it can be flushed by the OS when the device is running low on memory.

Since my entire code has been written synchonously and I don't have the leisure of rewriting the code for this particular project, I am looking for a direct replacement for `localStorage` that must be **synchronous**, **not** **a**synchronous and that will persist the stored data without the threat of flushing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no synchronous solution. Cordova storage plugins are asynchronous by the nature of the underlying technology for bridging web and native functionality. Webview-backed storage options are also asynchronous by their nature.

Your best option is to convert to an asynchronous storage API. I know you don't want to, but you might be able to speed things up a bit by using ES2017's async/await feature, and then transpile using TypeScript or Babel to ES5. This feature requires that the API you use returns promises, but there's generally lots of options for that out there.

Comment: there is still no synchronous storage method?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use [JSStore](http://jsstore.net/Tutorial/). It is not made for Cordova and I'm not completely sure it works, but it is worth the shoot. When you specify the onSuccess parameter, it returns the **data**, not a promise, as most data persistence API calls do.

I would only recommend it's usage in cases like yours, where a big refactoring is needed to use a form of persistence that uses asynchronous API calls. Even then, you should test the loss of performance of your application.

EDIT: According to the [Cordova's storage options page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html), IndexedDB, persistence mode used in JSStore, only works in Windows, Blackberry 10 and Android (4.4+), so it wouldn't solve your problem. That means that the only way out is refactoring your code to fit the async APIs.